# Is the managed package 'Nonprofit Starter Pack - Contacts & Organizations' only for Non Profits?

Tags: npsp

The benefit of [Contacts and Organizations for the Nonprofit Starter Pack 2](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GLGAEA4) is that it is a non-permanent alternative to person accounts, as that feature cannot be de-activated once active.

However, I'm curious if this is only for Non Profits, or whether it is for all Salesforce orgs apart from Professional edition but is merely marketed as being most suitable to Non Profits? I suspect it is the latter but thought best to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strongly geared towards non-profits, and includes some nomenclature that clearly suggests it's for non-profits, but any B2C-style organization can benefit from the design. In fact, we ourselves are a B2C organization, as we sell almost exclusively to individuals, not other businesses, and our data model, while not actually using the NPSP pack, is modeled very closely after it in terms of how our contacts and accounts are laid out.

However, with many of the new advanced features that have come out in Winter '17 and those coming in the next few releases, you might want to explore the new features available natively as well. I suggest you set up a sandbox or developer account, install the NPSP and try it out, and then go through the [Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/admin_intro_accounts_contacts/admin_intro_accounts_contacts_relationships) regarding the new Contact Relationship feature to see if that suits your needs instead. Salesforce has become a lot more B2C friendly in the past release or two, and I expect that this trend will continue into the future.